# Spacing adjustment for gridspec subfigures

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I wanted to change the size of `hspace` on my figure without using `constrained_layout=True`.

Here is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
# fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
GridSpec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2, figure= fig, hspace=0.9)

subfigure_1= fig.add_subfigure(GridSpec[0,:])
subplots_1= subfigure_1.subplots(1,1)

subfigure_2= fig.add_subfigure(GridSpec[1,:])
subplots_2= subfigure_2.subplots(1,1)

plt.show()
```

With `constrained_layout=True`, it works but sometimes I am faced other issues that I don't want with this setting set to `True`. (Moreover it seems that `constrained_layout=True` disables `width_ratios` on gridSpec.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using `hspace` however `fig.add_subfigure` and the `.suplots` in your code was confusing gridspec on how to construct the figure and apply `hspace`. Instead you can call gridspec by using `fig.add_subplot` directly (I'm using `hspace=0.1` so that the change is obvious):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
GridSpec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2, figure=fig, hspace=0.1)

subplots_1 = fig.add_subplot(GridSpec[0, :])
subplots_2 = fig.add_subplot(GridSpec[1, :])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However I have to use add_subfigure (in order to have different background with facecolor). So do you have any ideas to solve this approach ?

Comment: Yeah this is not the solution if you really have to use `.add_subfigure`. However, do you know you can have different background suplots with `ax.set_facecolor()`? In your code it would be `subplots_1.set_facecolor('red')` / `subplots_2.set_facecolor('blue')`  for example.

Comment: set_facecolor only colors the ax but not the entire figure (label, title, ...)

Comment: I see, yeah my solution won't work then. I think changing your question to 'Spacing adjustment for subfigures' to make it super clear that you need subfigures might help you :)

Comment: Also, on top of my head, there is also `tight_layout` which is different from `contrained_layout` - it might be worth a try?

Comment: It seems to not solve the issue.